# CBS Pending reboot after rebooting

Tags: windows, windows-update, windows-server-2016

OS: Windows server 2016 Datacenter Evaluation Build 14393

I think this may due to a suddenly shutdown during booing after "add roles and features".

I have tried to delete registry key

```
 HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\Reboot Pending\
```

However:

1. I still cannot do anything on Server Manager, they still found I have pending reboot;
2. After rebooting, this key shows again.

And I notice that there are a lots of pending packages (and they are not installed) under "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\PackagesPending"

So, how to get these pending packages installed? (or perform a revert?)

[image: Regedit]

[image: Manager]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if these operations would cause any other problems (and if it safe to do so.), but at least I can install features now. And these are what I've done.

It's important to backup before doing these.

Basically, I'm cleaning CBS update pending records.

1. Open `regedit`, find `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing`. You will see `PackagesPending`, right click it, open `Permission`. Click on `Advanced`, change owner to Administrator (or any other users you are using). Close `Advanced` Window. Give that user `Full Control` in `Permission` Window. And delete `PackagesPending`.
2. Repeat 1. to `Reboot Pending`
3. Open `X:\Windows\WinSxS` in `explorer`, you will see `pending.xml`. In its Properties, repeat 1. And delete `pending.xml`.
4. Reboot and everything looks well now.

And, don't forget backup registry and files you deleted.